# Get version ID of uploaded S3 file right after upload?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm dealing with the inevitable issue of users being able to overwrite files in my bucket via a JavaScript S3 upload.

After uploading a file, assuming I have versioning enabled, is there a way to get the original version ID so I can store it in my database for retrieval later when displaying that file?

This is my current upload code:

```
s3.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
                var uploaded = Math.round(evt.loaded / evt.total * 100);
                console.log(`File uploaded: ${uploaded}%`);
            }).send(function(err, data) {
                if(err){
                    alert(err);
                } else {
                    alert('File is uploaded successfully!');
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
```

I do not see any version ID in the data response since it seems to be in the response headers. Is there a way to extract it from there?

Comment: You could have Amazon S3 trigger an AWS Lambda function whenever an object **or new version** is created in an S3 bucket. The Lambda function could then update your database automatically whenever an upload happens.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein right now I'm calling listObjectVersions right after upload to get the new verison ID. Is there any reason this might not work?

Answer (score 1):

You're right; your code doesn't have access to the previous/original `versionId.`

I don't know your exact requirements, but I see two ways how to do this:

1. Check the file metadata before `upload` with [s3.headObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#headObject-property) which return `data.VersionId`. If the file doesn't exist, it doesn't matter; otherwise, you can save the original version ID in DB.
2. Don't save the versions in the DB at all, and fetch them with [listObjectVersions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjectVersions-property) when the file is displayed from S3.

Comment: The second option sounds simple, but would it create a lot of overhead? There are places in my page where I need to display 5 different files from S3 all at once. Would calling listObjectVersions for each slow the page load a lot?

Comment: @AnthonyFrizalone yeah, that sounds problematic; I'd keep the versions along with your data then.

Comment: Not fully understanding the first option. Could I instead upload the file, then call listObjectVersions immediately after and save the sole version ID in my database? Your first proposed solution sounds like that'd be called the second time someone tries to write the file.

Comment: Was able to call listObjectVersions immediately after upload to grab the original version ID. Is there any reason this shouldn't work?

Comment: Both variants work. Let's discuss yours:

1. there is no file, user uploads it; `listObjectVersions` returns one item in `data.Versions`
2. user uploads it again, `listObjectVersions` returns two items in `data.Versions`, and so on; the list grows every time the user overwrites the file

The method doesn't guarantee `data.Versions` ordering explicitly; I'd expect it's ordered, but that's up to you to verify.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve the original version ID immediately after upload using the following code (it uploads the image and then grabs the version right after using listObjectVersions):

```
s3.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) {
                var uploaded = Math.round(evt.loaded / evt.total * 100);
                console.log(`File uploaded: ${uploaded}%`);
            }).send(function(err, data) {
                if(err){
                    alert(err);
                } else {
                    alert('File is uploaded successfully!');
                    console.log(data);
                    var params = {
                      Bucket: "mybucket", 
                      Prefix: "images/path-to-image.jpg"
                     };
                     s3.listObjectVersions(params, function(err, data) {
                       var versionId = data["Versions"][0]["VersionId"];
                       alert(versionId);
                   });
                }
            });
```

Be sure to have list object versions enabled in your bucket policy:

```
{
        "Sid": "Statement2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucketVersions",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
    }
```